# positive elements in $C^*$ algebras and states

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I have problems to prove that an element $a $ is a $C^*$-algebra is positive if and only if $f(a) \geq 0$ for all states $f$.

The definitions I use: 
-$f:A\to\mathbb{C}$ linear functional on a C*-algebra A is called positive, if $f(a^*a)\ge 0$ for every a in A. 
-a state f is a positive functional with norm 1. 
-$a\ge0$, this means a is selfadjoint and $\sigma(a)\subseteq[0,\|a\|]$. 
The direction => is clear. But i stuck on <=.
If i follow the hint, i use the representation theorem: I have a universal representation $(H,g)$ of A and is $x\in A$, a positive linear functional $f:A\to\mathbb{C}\; f(b)=\langle g(b)x,x\rangle $ such that $f(a)\ge 0$. This is similar as you can see in Murphys book, Theorem 3.4.3. But now, i can't say that $g(a)$ is selfadjoint, because a is not selfadjoint in general. How can i continue? Regards 
An other hint is: First consider $A\cong C_0(X)$ commutative. But i dont know to prove this with this hint. 
 Maybe you could prove it without the representiation theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a\in A$ such that $\varphi(a)\geq0$ for all states $\varphi$. As $\varphi(\operatorname{Im} a)=\operatorname{Im} \varphi(a)=0$, we get $\operatorname{Im} a=0$ (by functional calculus, as the point evaluations are states) and so $a=a^*$. Knowing that $a$ is selfadjoint we can do the following. If it were not positive, it has $\lambda<0$ in its spectrum; using functional calculus, we can get a state (a character, actually) $\varphi$ with $\varphi(a)=\lambda<0$.

Comment: "using functional calculus, we can get a state (a character, actually) $\phi$
 with $\phi(a)=\lambda<0$." Can you please tell how? I don't know how to use functional calculus here because functional calculus gives an isomorphism between $C(\sigma(a))$ and $C^*(a)$. But a state $\phi$ belongs to neither $C(\sigma(a))$  nor $C^*(a)$. Thanks!

Comment: If $\Gamma:C^*(a)\to C(\sigma(a))$ is the canonical  isomorphism given by the Gelfand transform, it maps $a$ to the identity function. Define $\phi(x)=(\Gamma(x))(\lambda)$.  Then $\phi(a)=\lambda$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami by functional calculus, why does any self-adjoint attain its norm at a state? Or is this meant in terms of absolute value?

Comment: Yes, for a general selfadjoint the norm will be the absolute value of the evaluation at a well-chosen state. But the point here is that for a selfadjoint $b$ all points in $\sigma(b)$ are of the form $\varphi(b)$ for some state $\varphi$.

Answer (score 1):

Asyou remarked, one direction is trivial from definitions. 
For the other direction you can use the following well known facts:

1) An element is positive if and only if its spectrum is contained in $[0,\infty )$

2) If $\lambda$ belongs to spectrum of $a$ then there exists a state $f$ such that $f(a)=\lambda$.

Comment: To be precise: An element $a$ is called positive iff its spectrum is contained in $[0,\infty)$ and $a^* = a$.